# Ubuntu Server 20.04 has ModemManager installed?

Tags: docker, ubuntu-20.04

how likely is to have a "clean" ModemManager installed in /usr/sbin on a Web only Ubuntu 20.04 server? The only thing I manually setup is Docker Engine and I deploy remotely with docker-compose. The SFTP service comes out of the box with this VPS.

Comment: i am unsure but foe what do you still need a modem management?

Comment: I didn't install it, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: if not needed `apt remove modenmanager*`

Comment: I find this running on all of my Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS and 22.04 LTS. Is it safe to remove it?